# how to dry code? (for python 3.6 django 1.10.5)

Tags: python, django

I do not know how to remove the overlap in the class.
And what if we want to change the datetime format?

```
from django.db import models


class A(models.Model):
 created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
class B(models.Model):
 created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
class C(models.Model):
 created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and don't forget to use abstract = True

`class BaseModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True`

or you will finish with 4 tables in your database including 'appname_basemodel' table

[django doc model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance to the rescue:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class A(BaseModel):
    pass

class B(BaseModel):
    pass

class C(BaseModel):
    pass
```

Now `A`, `B` and `C` all have `created_time` and `updated_time`.

As for the second question about datetime format, you will not worry about that part in your models. The objects returned by `created_time` on  an instance of `A` for example, will be a Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object which can be formatted with [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) in your views (here is [a good cheatsheet](http://strftime.org/) for the format codes), or with the [`date` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date) in your templates.